# Load Pandas data frames Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to build a recommendation system using TensorFlow recommenders (https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/quickstart)

in their quick start they're loading the data like this

`ratings = tfds.load('movielens/100k-ratings', split="train")`

I have a .csv file how to put it in the same format as the data they're passing in?

Also I would like to use .map on the tf data

EX: `ratings = ratings .map(lambda x: {"itemId": x["itemId"],"userId": x["userId"]})`

Comment: Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` to read the values from a pandas dataframe --> [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe)

Comment: Apart from using `tf.data.Dataset` as mentioned by @queste, you can try using the `CsvDataset` which is an experimental feature. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset).

Comment: thank you, I solved it using the `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. however to use the `.map` you have to cast the pandas df to a dictionary. `ratings = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df_ratings_train)))`